# Trouble with plugin styles in admin area of Wordpress

Tags: plugins, css

I am creating a plugin and noticed in the admin area that my h2 and h3 tags are not showing correctly. They are the same size and not bold. I clicked inspect element, and it shows both headers having the same size and being set by load-styles.php:6. If I look at this file in wp-admin. it doesn't show the header tags, so not sure where it is coming from.

I have the plugin's css file enqueued correctly, and the front end looks fine. It's just the admin area that doesn't look right. i tried putting the following in the css file, but it didn't make any difference.

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
```

I do have bootstrap and jquery enqueued, but not sure if that is the issue. That was creating an issue with me for something else, but was able to add that to the css file to overwrite what bootstrap was doing, so don't think this is a bootstrap issue.

Any help is appreciated. I pasted a screenshot of what I am seeing when I inspect element.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework that’s intended to be the base layer of styles on any page. WordPress already has its own styles in the admin, so it doesn’t make sense to load a framework on top of them  you’ll just get unexpected results like this. The only workaround would be to add a 3rd set of styles, written by you, that resolves any conflicts.